# Can Stanford-NLP detect interrogative sentence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sharpnlp

I have been doing some basic tweaking with Stanford-NLP for last few days. I have read about Link Grammar too. If anyone have used any of these libraries, is it possible to detect interrogative sentence using any of them? Currently I am stuck in Stanford-NLP. I might have to add a large sum of code for it to work. It looks like i might need to create a separate PCFG.

Comment: I'm seeking answer for this question too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice: don't use a PCFG for that. Use Stanford NLP's excellent MaxEnt classifier to do binary classification interrogative / non interrogative. It will work really well. You have to prepare a corpus with a few dozen examples of each class at least, maybe more depending on your sentences.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Do you have an example of how to use it ? I tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879551/nltk-find-if-a-sentence-is-in-a-questioning-form but is not 100% correct.