# Stanford nlp for python

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

All I want to do is find the sentiment (positive/negative/neutral) of any given string. On researching I came across Stanford NLP. But sadly its in Java. Any ideas on how can I make it work for python?

Comment: Looks like dasmith on GitHub wrote a nice little wrapper for this: https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python

Comment: NLTK contains a wrapper for Stanford NLP, though I'm not sure if it includes sentiment analysis. Calling an external utility - in Java or whatever - from Python is not hard.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## Use [`py-corenlp`](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp/)

### Download [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/)

The latest version at this time (2020-05-25) is 4.0.0:

```
wget https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-4.0.0.zip https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-4.0.0-models-english.jar
```

If you do not have [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), you probably have [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/):

```
curl https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-4.0.0.zip -O https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-4.0.0-models-english.jar -O
```

If all else fails, use the browser ;-)

### Install the package

```
unzip stanford-corenlp-4.0.0.zip
mv stanford-corenlp-4.0.0-models-english.jar stanford-corenlp-4.0.0
```

### Start the [server](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html)

```
cd stanford-corenlp-4.0.0
java -mx5g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 10000
```

Notes:

1. `timeout` is in milliseconds, I set it to 10 sec above.
   You should increase it if you pass huge blobs to the server.
2. There are [more options](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#command-line-flags), you can list them with `--help`.
3. `-mx5g` should allocate enough [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14763079/850781), but YMMV and you may need to modify the option if your box is underpowered.

### Install the python package

The standard package

```
pip install pycorenlp
```

does *not* work with Python 3.9, so you need to do

```
pip install git+https://github.com/sam-s/py-corenlp.git
```

(See also [the official list](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/other-languages.html)).

### Use it

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
res = nlp.annotate("I love you. I hate him. You are nice. He is dumb",
                   properties={
                       'annotators': 'sentiment',
                       'outputFormat': 'json',
                       'timeout': 1000,
                   })
for s in res["sentences"]:
    print("%d: '%s': %s %s" % (
        s["index"],
        " ".join([t["word"] for t in s["tokens"]]),
        s["sentimentValue"], s["sentiment"]))
```

and you will get:

```
0: 'I love you .': 3 Positive
1: 'I hate him .': 1 Negative
2: 'You are nice .': 3 Positive
3: 'He is dumb': 1 Negative
```

## Notes

1. You pass the whole text to the server and it splits it into sentences. It also splits sentences into tokens.
2. The sentiment is ascribed to each *sentence*, not the *whole text*. The [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) `sentimentValue` across sentences can be used to estimate the sentiment of the whole text.
3. The average sentiment of a sentence is between `Neutral` (2) and `Negative` (1), the range is from `VeryNegative` (0) to `VeryPositive` (4) which appear to be quite rare.
4. You can [stop the server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#stopping-the-server) either by typing <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> at the terminal you started it from or using the shell command `kill $(lsof -ti tcp:9000)`. `9000` is the default port, you can change it using the `-port` option when starting the server.
5. Increase `timeout` (in milliseconds) in server or client if you get timeout errors.
6. `sentiment` is just **one** annotator, there are [many more](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/annotators.html), and you can request several, separating them by comma: `'annotators': 'sentiment,lemma'`.
7. Beware that the sentiment model is somewhat idiosyncratic (e.g., [the result is different depending on whether you mention David or Bill](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/351)).

**PS**. I cannot believe that I added a **9th** answer, but, I guess, I had to, since none of the existing answers helped me (some of the 8 previous answers have now been deleted, some others have been converted to comments).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think it is the only one that is promising. But I wonder is there any other way to pass the sentences. Suppose I have a large .txt file with more than 10,000 lines and each line per sentence. What is the appropriate way for me to use? Thanks!

Comment: if you will find that you cannot pass all 10k lines in a single blob, you can split it arbitrarily (note that your sentence "each line per sentence" is unclear).

Comment: @user5779223: another option is to increase timeout - see edit.

Comment: Inside `for s in res["sentences"]`, Is there a way to print this beautifully like http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sentiment/rntnDemo.html ?

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal: not OOTB. The information _is_ contained in the response, but you need a library for visual representation.

Comment: Is there a Widows equivalent to this?

Comment: @NickTheInventor: there is nothing platform-specific here. Both Java and Python run identically on Unix and Windows.

Comment: For those who experience an error `Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap` on running CoreNLP Server, use `java -cp "*" -Xmx1500m edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -timeout 15000` instead, limiting Java to run at 1.5GB memory only.

Comment: instead `#java -mx4g -cp "*;stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000` works. else it gives error

Comment: Hi, as of 2020 Stanford NLP provides a Stanford CoreNLP Client for Stanza. It is called Stanford CoreNLP Client and the documentation can be found here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html

Answer (score 6):

## Native Python implementation of NLP tools from Stanford

Recently Stanford has released a new [Python packaged](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/index.html) implementing neural network (NN) based algorithms for the most important NLP tasks:

- tokenization
- multi-word token (MWT) expansion
- lemmatization
- part-of-speech (POS) and morphological features tagging
- dependency parsing

It is implemented in Python and uses PyTorch as the NN library. The package contains accurate models for more than [50 languages](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/installation_download.html#human-languages-supported-by-stanfordnlp).

To install you can use PIP:

```
pip install stanfordnlp
```

To perform basic tasks you can use native Python interface with [many NLP algorithms](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/processors.html):

```
import stanfordnlp

stanfordnlp.download('en')   # This downloads the English models for the neural pipeline
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline() # This sets up a default neural pipeline in English
doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He was elected president in 2008.")
doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()
```

EDIT:

So far, the library **does not support sentiment analysis**, yet I'm not deleting the answer, since it directly answers the "Stanford nlp for python" part of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I was trying to do something similar(Analyze sentiments on statements). After reading your post I came to know that stanfordnlp for python is not yet supporting sentiments.

Answer (score 2):

Right now they have STANZA.

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/

**Release History**
Note that prior to version 1.0.0, the Stanza library was named as “StanfordNLP”. To install historical versions prior to to v1.0.0, you’ll need to run pip install stanfordnlp.

So, it confirms that Stanza is the full python version of stanford NLP.

Comment: As of 2020 this is the best answer to this question, as Stanza is native python, so no need to run the Java package. Available through pip or conda.

Comment: Very slow!  Big downside.

Answer (score 1):

`Textblob` is a great package for sentimental analysis written in `Python`. You can have the [docs here](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/dev/) . Sentimental analysis of any given sentence is carried out by inspecting words and their corresponding emotional score (sentiment). You can start with

```
$ pip install -U textblob
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

First pip install command will give you latest version of textblob installed in your (`virtualenv`) system since you pass `-U will upgrade the pip package its latest available version` . And the next will download all the data required, the`corpus` .

Comment: I actually tried using Textblob but the sentiment scores are pretty off. Hence I was planning to switch to stanford nlp instead

Comment: Have you tried `wrapper` mentioned in the other answer?

Comment: "Sentimental analysis" (-:

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar situation. Most of my projects are in Python and sentiment part is Java. Luckily it's quite easy to lean how to use the stanford CoreNLP jar.

Here is one of my scripts and you can download jars and run it.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.ArrayCoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class Simple_NLP {
static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    public static void init() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    }

    public static String findSentiment(String tweet) {
        String SentiReturn = "";
        String[] SentiClass ={"very negative", "negative", "neutral", "positive", "very positive"};

        //Sentiment is an integer, ranging from 0 to 4. 
        //0 is very negative, 1 negative, 2 neutral, 3 positive and 4 very positive.
        int sentiment = 2;

        if (tweet != null && tweet.length() > 0) {
            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(tweet);

            List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
            if (sentences != null && sentences.size() > 0) {

                ArrayCoreMap sentence = (ArrayCoreMap) sentences.get(0);                
                Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);  
                sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);             
                SentiReturn = SentiClass[sentiment];
            }
        }
        return SentiReturn;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem : maybe a solution with [stanford_corenlp_py](https://github.com/e5c/stanford_corenlp_py) that uses `Py4j` as pointed out by @roopalgarg.

> ## stanford_corenlp_py
>
> This repo provides a Python interface for calling the "sentiment" and "entitymentions" annotators of Stanford's CoreNLP Java package, current as of v. 3.5.1. It uses py4j to interact with the JVM; as such, in order to run a script like scripts/runGateway.py, you must first compile and run the Java classes creating the JVM gateway.

Answer (score 0):

### Use stanfordcore-nlp python library

stanford-corenlp is a really good wrapper on top of the stanfordcore-nlp to use it in python.

`wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05.zip`

### Usage

```
# Simple usage
from stanfordcorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP

nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('/Users/name/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05')

sentence = 'Guangdong University of Foreign Studies is located in Guangzhou.'
print('Tokenize:', nlp.word_tokenize(sentence))
print('Part of Speech:', nlp.pos_tag(sentence))
print('Named Entities:', nlp.ner(sentence))
print('Constituency Parsing:', nlp.parse(sentence))
print('Dependency Parsing:', nlp.dependency_parse(sentence))

nlp.close() # Do not forget to close! The backend server will consume a lot memory.
```

[More info](https://github.com/Lynten/stanford-corenlp)

Comment: Can you please explain how this stanfordcorenlp can be used to analyze the sentiment of the statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the TextBlob library. A sample implementation goes like this:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
def sentiment(message):
    # create TextBlob object of passed tweet text
    analysis = TextBlob(message)
    # set sentiment
    return (analysis.sentiment.polarity)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very new progress on this issue:

Now you can use `stanfordnlp` package inside the python:

From the [README](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp):

```
>>> import stanfordnlp
>>> stanfordnlp.download('en')   # This downloads the English models for the neural pipeline
>>> nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline() # This sets up a default neural pipeline in English
>>> doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He was elected president in 2008.")
>>> doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

inputFile = 'senti_post3.csv'

# Add empty column columns
df = pd.read_csv(inputFile)
df.head(5)

# header_list_new = ['numSentence', 'numWords', 'totSentiment', 'avgSentiment', 'Sfreq0','Sfreq1','Sfreq2','Sfreq3','Sfreq4','Sfreq5']
# for i, name in enumerate(header_list_new):
#     df[name] = 0

from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')

# Function; Output = # sentence, # words, avg.sentimentValue, sentimentHist
def stanford_sentiment(text_str):
    res = nlp.annotate(text_str,
                   properties={
                       'annotators': 'sentiment',
                       'outputFormat': 'json',
                       'timeout': 40000,
                   })
    numSentence = len(res["sentences"])
    numWords = len(text_str.split())
    
    # data arrangement
    arraySentVal = np.zeros(numSentence)

    for i, s in enumerate(res["sentences"]):
        arraySentVal[i] = int(s["sentimentValue"])

    # sum of sentiment values 
    totSentiment = sum(arraySentVal)

    # avg. of sentiment values 
    avgSentiment = np.mean(arraySentVal)

    # frequency of sentimentValue
    bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    freq = np.histogram(arraySentVal, bins)[0]    # getting freq. only w/o bins

    return(numSentence, numWords, totSentiment, avgSentiment, freq)
# dfLength = len(df)
# for i in range(dfLength):
for i in range(54000,55284):
    try:
        numSentence, numWords, totSentiment, avgSentiment, freq = stanford_sentiment(df.clean_text[i].replace('\n'," "))
        df.loc[i,'numSentence'] = numSentence
        df.loc[i,'numWords'] = numWords
        df.loc[i,'totSentiment'] = totSentiment
        df.loc[i,'avgSentiment'] = avgSentiment
        df.loc[i,'Sfreq0'] = freq[0]
        df.loc[i,'Sfreq1'] = freq[1]
        df.loc[i,'Sfreq2'] = freq[2]
        df.loc[i,'Sfreq3'] = freq[3]
        df.loc[i,'Sfreq4'] = freq[4]
        df.loc[i,'Sfreq5'] = freq[5]
    except:
        print("error where i =", i)
  
outputFile = 'senti_post16.csv'
df.to_csv(outputFile, encoding='utf-8', index=False )
```

Comment: useful link: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sentiment-feature-extraction-using-stanford-corenlp-python-jupyter-notebook-29a0d97ca76f