# Using Stanford nlp's sentiment engine with python parser?

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a project where I am planning to use the [Stanford's sentiment analysis model](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/) to do my sentiment analysis.

I have tried NLTK's stanford parser but couldn't get the sentiment analysis module in it. Can anyone point me to that module, and if possible give a working example. If not NLTK is there any other wrapper that I should be looking into.

Any answer with a working example will be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stanford nlp for python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879532/stanford-nlp-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

(from same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879532/stanford-nlp-for-python) )

---

I am facing the same problem : maybe a solution with [stanford_corenlp_py](https://github.com/e5c/stanford_corenlp_py) that uses `Py4j` as pointed out by @roopalgarg.

> ## stanford_corenlp_py
>
> This repo provides a Python interface for calling the "sentiment" and "entitymentions" annotators of Stanford's CoreNLP Java package, current as of v. 3.5.1. It uses py4j to interact with the JVM; as such, in order to run a script like scripts/runGateway.py, you must first compile and run the Java classes creating the JVM gateway.