# Function vs Content Words

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

How do I distinguish between [function/structure words and content/lexical words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word)?

I am already using [StanfordCoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP), so I would like to leverage it, if possible.

More specifically, which [annotator](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/annotators.html) should I use and how would it mark content/lexical words?

I tried [`pos`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) but it  does not distinguish between function and content words.

PS. I use the `lemma` annotator to get the words which I want to ignore.

PPS. I use [`pyconlp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496870/850781).

Comment: If you use the version of Stanford CoreNLP from GitHub we do distribute a stop words list with it.  It's at this path: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/data/edu/stanford/nlp/patterns/surface/stopwords.txt

Comment: This link shows an example of using the API in Java: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: So one thing you could do is iterate through the tokens and see if they are in the list of stop words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function words (stop words) are often manually curated because they vary by domain. You can find a general purpose list in NLTK. CoreNLP also has one [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/data/edu/stanford/nlp/patterns/surface/stopwords.txt)

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stops = stopwords.words('english')
```

However, you should still look at them to see if they make sense for you use case. I have recently been working with technical language, so I removed 'it' from my list because 'IT' is an acronym in this domain and thus a content word.

For your annotator, you could go with the general purpose TokenizerAnnotator which will split your text into "words". You can then check each word to see if it exists in your stopword list. If you are working with strings, just try splitting them on whitespace and removing or marking stopwords as a gut check.