# py-corenlp - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, stanford-nlp

I followed this answer:
[Stanford nlp for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879532/stanford-nlp-for-python/40496870#40496870)

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
from newspaper import Article

url = u'newsArticle.example.html'
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()


LARGE_TEXT=article.text


res = nlp.annotate(LARGE_TEXT,
               properties={
                   'annotators': 'sentiment',
                   'outputFormat': 'json',
                   'timeout': 1000,
               })
for s in res["sentences"]:
    print ("%d: '%s': %s %s" % (
        s["index"],
        " ".join([t["word"] for t in s["tokens"]]),
        s["sentimentValue"], s["sentiment"]))
```

I used a longer text as input and encountered following error:

```
 for s in res["sentences"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was **'timeout': 1000**

I changed it to **'timeout': 10000**